# get the name of a visual studio project using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I am building an extension to do a custom build of my visual studio projects. For this I need to know the name of my project I have selected. How will I be able to get this ?I am writing my plugin in C#.I use visual studio 2017.

Comment: Do you need your project name in runtime?

Comment: The name of the project I have selected. Yes at runtime.

Comment: @ritu Did it work for you? Still got any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the current project hierarchy. I got it from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/27342bf3-672b-455d-8155-3883ea3e0928/faq-12-how-do-i-get-a-current-selected-project-item?forum=vsx).

```
IntPtr hierarchyPtr, selectionContainerPtr;    
Object prjItemObject  = null;    
IVsMultiItemSelect mis;    
uint prjItemId;

IVsMonitorSelection monitorSelection = (IVsMonitorSelection) Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellMonitorSelection));    
monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection(out hierarchyPtr, out prjItemId, out mis, out selectionContainerPtr);

IVsHierarchy selectedHierarchy = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(hierarchyPtr, typeof(IVsHierarchy)) asIVsHierarchy;

if (selectedHierarchy != null)    
{    
    ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(selectedHierarchy.GetProperty(prjItemId, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject, out prjItemObject));    
}
   var projectItem = objProj as EnvDTE.ProjectItem;
```

Please check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/24f71d7f-bb7d-4df8-a00a-ff0ce6f4d48f/vspackage-access-to-svsmdcodedomproviderivsmdcodedomprovider?forum=vsx) discussion if you like to know more in detail.

Comment: When I try to print the name of selectedPrjItem by doing 
MessageBox.Show(selectedPrjItem.Name); I get the error :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.How do I access the value?

Comment: Can you please check wheter selectedPrjItem  is null or not? I think this error refers to that only.

Comment: Are you getting anything in prjItemObject ?